# Как учесть обновление приложения?

Tags: java, android

Собираюсь выложить приложение на PlayMarket, с последующим его обновлением.

Что мне надо предусмотреть заранее?

В файлах приложения находятся файлы настроек и база данных, нужно чтобы они остались там же и приложение после обновления их подхватило.

Что посоветуете почитать, на что обратить внимание?

Comment: при обновлении через Play Market и настройки и БД останутся "там же" и приложение их "подхватит"  без вашего дополнительного участия.

Comment: Единственная сложность, которая может возникнуть - если вы будете расширять базу данных (добавлять новые поля). Для этого, понятно, надо прописать метод `onUpdateDataBase`. Во всём остальном, если вы не собираетесь менять названия базы или `SharedPreferences`, всё будет "подхвачено".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Продумайте заранее историю с версионностью приложения. На это многие не обращают почти никакого внимания, а между тем зря.

Типичный use case который возникает с версионностью выглядит так:

1. Юзер сообщает о баге
2. Девелопер резонно спрашивает номер версии
3. Юзер говорит что-типа версия `XX.YY.ZZZ`
4. Далее девелопер конкретно сдувается, потому что он не понимает какие конкретно модификации исходников были в версии `XX.YY.ZZZ`

У меня есть свой способ выработанный горьким опытом. В `build.gradle` пишем  небольшие скриптики.

Этот скрипт возвращает номер ревизии в `git` стартуя с корневого:

```
def getRevision = { ->
    try {
        def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
        exec {
            standardOutput = stdout
            commandLine 'git', 'rev-list', '--first-parent', '--count', 'master'
        }
        println("Build #"+stdout)
        return asInteger(stdout.toString("ASCII").trim())
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Далее определяем версию аппы как:

```
/*
Version number encoding: XX.YY.ZZZB
XX 2 digits - major version
YY 2 digits - minor version
ZZZ 3 digits - build order (starting from head)
B 1 digit - build variation/patch
Example: 01234561 is version 1.23.456a
*/

def char[] patches='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyz'.toCharArray()
def majorVersion=1
def minorVersion=0
def revision=getRevision()
def patch=-1 // -1 - no patch

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "blah-blah"
    targetSdkVersion targetSdkVersionVar
    if (patch >= 0) {
        versionName = majorVersion + '.' + minorVersion + '.' + revision + patches[patch]
        versionCode = 10000000*majorVersion+10000*minorVersion + 10*revision+patch
    } else {
        versionName = majorVersion + '.' + minorVersion + '.' + revision
        versionCode = 10000000*majorVersion+10000*minorVersion + 10*revision
    }
}
```

В этом случае номер версии будет генерировать автоматически. Нужно будет при необходимости только задавать номера старших и младших версий, а build будет всегда актуальным.

Comment: Чем нумеровать коммиты (кстати, надо еще суметь по номеру коммита уметь искать сам коммит), не проще добавлять tag с версией к коммиту во время билда?

Comment: Я не стал приводить весь код. У меня так и есть. К билду еще добавляется хэш коммита (в `git` как известно нет номеров коммитов, есть только хэши)

Comment: Если в версии присутствует хэш, то зачем нужна переменная revision? Не совсем понятно. Просто по revision получить хэш не так просто, вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120001/what-is-the-git-equivalent-for-revision-number) народ извращается... И это подразумевает дополнительные телодвижения. В то время как tag'ание билдов дает просто `git checkout tags/XX.YY.ZZZ`

Comment: `revision` нужен для того, чтобы обеспечить инкремент `versioncode`